# Split integer to array based on size using javascript

Tags: javascript

It may be silly but i need to write an logic to get integer to split to array based on size.
For example if integer is 13 i need to convert to array as [5,5,3] if my size is 5.
if size is 10 then array should be [10,3].
Can any one help me writing the logic in javascript?.

Comment: Please add the code you've tried

Comment: I can't find logic from the logic ..?

Comment: You're getting downvoted because people want you to figure out the homework for yourself. Hint: Count up to 5. Push to array. Count to 5 again. Push. If your counter hits the limit, push one more time and stop.

Comment: Generators are really handy for this -> `function* splitInt(value, size) { while (value - size > 0) { yield(size); value -= size; }; yield value; }`  You can then use like -> `console.log([...splitInt(13, 5)])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may build up an array of size `N/n` if there's no remainder from division (`N%n`), or `N/n+1` if there is one.

Then you may simply [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) through that array and populate the result with `n` or use remainder as the last element if one exists:

```js
const num = 13,
      size = 5,
      
      splitNumber = (N, n) =>
        [...Array(0|N/n+(N%n ? 1 : 0))]
          .map((_,i,s) =>
            N%n && i == s.length-1 ? N%n : n)
        
console.log(splitNumber(13,5))
console.log(splitNumber(13,10))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```